# Reverse geocoding to get city, state, country data separately?

Tags: python, r, reverse-geocoding

I have longitude and latitude data. I need to reverse geocode to get city, state, country data separately.

I have checked google service.

Google provides complete address to a micro level. Separation into city, state, country seems not possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the [Google reverse geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) will break it down for you, take a look at this result:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

If you switch out `xml` with `json`, you can get json instead. Another option could be the [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Example) service, which also returns either xml or json.